# Step functions/Heaviside Functions MATLAB error

Tags: matlab, function, inline, piecewise

So im trying to plot f(t) which is a piecewise function using heaviside and ezplot functions in MATLAB.   Now im not very familiar with MATLAB at all.  If anyone knows why im getting this error it would be helpful.

> f = '12+(-2t+8)*heaviside(t-2)+(2t-12)*heaviside(t-6)'
>
> f = 12+(-2t+8)*heaviside(t-2)+(2t-12)*heaviside(t-6)
>
> ezplot(f)

Error using inlineeval (line 15) Error in inline expression ==> 12+(-2t+8).*heaviside(t-2)+(2t-12).*heaviside(t-6)  Error: Unexpected MATLAB expression.

Error in inline/feval (line 34)
        INLINE_OUT_ = inlineeval(INLINE_INPUTS_, INLINE_OBJ_.inputExpr, INLINE_OBJ_.expr);

Error in ezplotfeval (line 52)
    z = feval(f,x(1));

Error in ezplot>ezplot1 (line 469)
    [y, f, loopflag] = ezplotfeval(f, x);

Error in ezplot (line 145)
                [hp, cax] = ezplot1(cax, f{1}, vars, labels, args{:});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell Matlab to multiply explicitly, use 2*t instead of 2t.

```
syms t real
f = 12+(-2*t+8)*heaviside(t-2)+(2*t-12)*heaviside(t-6)
ezplot(f,[0 10])
```